# How to stop main thread and get possibility to stop all flow in RxJava

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, rx-java

I need to stop main thread and get the possibility to stop flow

I use

```
.subscribe();
```

The main thread do not stop, but i get the `Disposable`, which i can use to stop all flow

But when i use

```
.blockingSubscribe();
```

It return void, and i cant stop all flowable, but the main thread stopped

I can use

```
.filter(s -> !stopService.get())
```

but it seems to get a better way to stop all flowable

1. Is there another way, to stop main thread and get a possibility to stop all flowable?
2. Maybe there is a way to use Disposable and some main thread blocking operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It return void, and i cant stop all flowable

There is no point in returning a `Disposable` because `blockingSubscribe` only returns when the flow terminates, thus having a `Disposable` after and disposing it has no effect.

You could use `takeUntil` with a `PublishProcessor` to request a termination while using `blockingSubscribe`.

```java
var stop = PublishProcessor.create();

// hand the processor to something that would signal it to stop, e.g.,

ForkJoinPool.commonPool().submit(() -> {
    System.out.println("Press ENTER to stop");
    System.in.read();
    stop.onComplete();
    return null; // to get submit(Callable)
});

source
.takeUntil(stop)
.blockingSubscribe();
```

In general, if you want to block the Java main thread, you'll need an asynchronous signal to get it unblocked.